# Firefox performance tool does not work on linux running on armhf

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

Tried installing other add-ons too. But nothing worked. Could I get some help on this?

Comment: Could we get some more details?

Comment: @Geshode : I have a processor built on armv7l architecture. The system has linux OS. I've installed firefox ( v52.0.2 ). However, all developer tools exists except performance tool. It has been greyed out.

Comment: Did you check settings section (of dev tools)? some tabs are not enabled by default

Comment: Is any more recent version available for your platform? https://redd.it/9q1abf reminds me that version 0.23 of the Gecko Profiler extension had a `strict_min_version` of 55.0a1.